# JQuery Load a page into a div and onload change content of second div

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page with 2 divs one is called menu and the other is called content. The content div loads a log in page. When a user tries to log in I call a script into the content div and if unsuccessful it reloads the log in page.

If it is successful I use header location to redirect to the logged in page. When this page loads in the content div i need it to change the menu div to a different menu. I have tried using the following but to no avail. Is there any way that when the successful page loads into the content div that it can automatically change the content of the menu div

this is what i have tried in logged in page that is loaded into content div  the body tag of that page has

> onLoad="$('div#menu').load('Includes/logged-menu-page.php')"

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of the `.load()` function is a callback function. You can use this to verify it loaded correctly and then edit your menu element:

```
$('#result').load('Includes/logged-menu-page.php', function() {
  if(loaded_correctly)
      $("div#menu").html("OtherMenu");
  else
      $("div#menu").html("LoginMenu");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Hanlet I still do not seem to be able to get it to work. The log in page with the menu and content div goes to a seperate script page called by jquery to check the users details in database once they are entered. if the mysql query comes back ok i use php header location to redirect to the logged in page which loads correctly into the content div. I have tried the above on the logged in page and i got as far as a the menu being changed but it was writing the name logged-menu-page in the menu div instead of loading the menu :)

Comment: Instead of loading content dynamically through jQuery, I would suggest you load your content dynamically through php. Remember any user can look at this jQuery code, and change it so that it will load the actual page instead of the menu. I wish I could help you more, but your specific scenario is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change which item you are calling the load function on:

`$('div#menu').load('Includes/logged-menu-page.php')`

should be

```
$('div#content').load(function() {
 // load your stuff to your menu div
 // you would probably need to make an ajax call or something here
});
```

I think this is what you are trying to do, but I am not sure what info you have in `logged-menu-page.php` from your question